# Find existence of number in a sorted list in constant time? (Interview question)

Tags: algorithm

I'm studying for upcoming interviews and have encountered this question several times (written verbatim)

> Find or determine non existence of a number in a sorted list of N numbers where the numbers range over M, M >> N and N large enough to span multiple disks.  Algorithm to beat O(log n); bonus points for constant time algorithm.

First of all, I'm not sure if this is a question with a real solution.  My colleagues and I have mused over this problem for weeks and it seems ill formed (of course, just because we can't think of a solution doesn't mean there isn't one).  A few questions I would have asked the interviewer are:

- Are there repeats in the sorted list?
- What's the relationship to the number of disks and N?

One approach I considered was to binary search the min/max of each disk to determine the disk that should hold that number, if it exists, then binary search on the disk itself.  Of course this is only an order of magnitude speedup if the number of disks is large and you also have a sorted list of disks.  I think this would yield some sort of O(log log n) time.

As for the M >> N hint, perhaps if you know how many numbers are on a disk and what the range is, you could use the pigeonhole principle to rule out some cases some of the time, but I can't figure out an order of magnitude improvement.

Also, "bonus points for constant time algorithm" makes me a bit suspicious.

Any thoughts, solutions, or relevant history of this problem?

Comment: I'm still curious about this, and I'd like to see another couple answers.

Comment: Why not use hashing (i.e., a distributed hash table)?

Comment: Oof, that could work, given a fast hash, and one of the mechanisms for keeping the space wastage down, but distributed hash tables aren't trivial.  Certainly nothing I'd want to write on a whiteboard in 40 minutes.  Still, it's not a fundamentally bad thought.  If I'm honest, I'd probably just yell Judy Arrays and run.

Comment: If it's a hashtable, though, it's not a sorted list. Also, note that "distributed hash table" actually refers to a quite different data structure than what you'd need - what you need is just a disk-based hashtable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strange enough the question is to determine the NON-EXISTENCE of a value, not the existence.

This may imply they refer to a Bloom filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  A Bloom filter can tell you whether an element:

- doesn't exist
- or possibly exists

Comment: Bloom filters are probabilistic. Also, the question says "find or determine non-existence", so it is not just non-existence. Even if it was just non-existence, there could be false positives (i.e. it does not exist, but we say it does).

Comment: Isn't construction of a Bloom filter O(n)?

Comment: @academicRobot: Yes, but I presume we can do that once and amortize it off :)

Comment: I think if this is given as an answer then it should be stated that it is a probabilistic algorithm that will help 'only' in 99% cases (well, it should be stated :). Also a strong argument that this is an actual answer lies in the example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Example) - it seems Google's Big Table uses this, so I would not be at least surprised if them or their competition/peers (everyone else?) would put this in the interview question (so I basically giving up my own answer :) )

Comment: I know that Venti, the filesystem underneath Plan 9 From Bell Labs solves a very similar question with bloom filters, but the size of your bloom filter has a relationship with n, and thus may grow past atomic operations.  When it does, it becomes a function of n to search through it, and that's before we consider false positives.  Building the bloom filter is also a function of n, generally at least linear.  Hash functions are also not free.  In short, I'd say it's certainly not constant time, even before the chance of a false positive.  Bloom filters are basically the best I can do though.

Comment: if we were allowed to use a second Bloom filter for those integers in the range M which are NOT in the original set, we could also tell for sure whether the element exists in `O(1)`. But it's probably impractical to construct another Bloom filter for a set of size M...

Answer (score 26):

Since the question does not state in which format the numbers are stored you can tell the interviewer that you are going to assume that the numbers are stored in a physical way. For example each number may be written on a card and each card is owned by one person.
[image]

> N large enough to span multiple disks

Now if you want to find or determine non existence of a number you could just ask the persons if the number you are looking for is on the card they are holding on.
[image]

If nobody answers within N seconds then the number is not there. This is assuming everybody can hear you and each person is aware of what number they have on their card.

I don't know much about physics (Speed of sound, air friction, time for each persons brain to look at their card etc)

Comment: @NickJohnson - true, but that's effort complexity.  time complexity has been reduced to O(1) by running the tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 12):

If only using comparisons, we have an Omega(log N) (worst case) lower bound (i.e. O(1) is not possible).

Say you decide to look at some position in the array, then your adversary can place the element in the part of the array which is larger.

Thus at each step, you have at least half the elements left to consider and so Omega(logn) in the worst case.

So you would probably need to get away from using just comparisons in order to do better than O(log N) in the worst case.

As some other answer mentioned, you could do a probabilistic constant time search which gives you the right answer with reasonable probability, for e.g. using Bloom Filters.

Answer (score 8):

By the letter of the question, they are probably looking for an interpolation search, which is average case O(log log n).  Yes, this is O(n) in worst case, but can be improved with knowledge of the distribution or using an interpolation-binary search.

This plays into the M >> N hint.  The average case analysis for interpolation search is pretty complex, so I won't even attempt a modification under M >> N.  But conceptual, under M >> N and assuming a uniform distribution, you can assume that the value will be bounded by +/-1 of the initial search position, yielding O(1).

A practical implementation could do the initial interpolation once, and if the search value is not bounded, fall back to a binary search.

Not sure how multiple disks could be used to advantage in this approach, though...

Comment: Perhaps one step of an initial interpolation gets you to the disk with the correct bounds, then you lop off a huge portion of your array?

Comment: +1, some notes: if distribution is not uniform the interpolation/extrapolation search can still be used if you know the distribution (with uniform distribution you have linear interpolation/extrapolation, with other distributions it is not linear but dependant on distribution). building perfect distribution representation could require a lot of space so some approximation/loss of precision would have to be utilized - it is unclear if that would remove the potential benefit.

Answer (score 4):

**First look**

M >> N is not a hint I think, it simply discourages creating a bitmap that would directly tell you in O(1) time if a number exists.

I think that sane assumption with N spanning multiple hard disks is that you can expect that you would not have order of magnitutde more disks at your disposal. As you would need 2<sup>M</sup> space for O(1) performance, and if N spans multiple disks then M spans >> multiple disks and 2<sup>M</sup> spans >> disks than available.

Also, it tells you that approach to store the *missing* numbers would not be efficient since then you would have to store X numbers where

X = M - N => X ~ M (since M >> N)

which is then a worse case.

So at first look it seems that you can prove that there is no known better answer.

EDIT:
I still stand at the above reasoning, which is also even better proven by Moron's answer. However the conclusion, after looking at Bloom Filter from Patrick's answer I believe that the interviewer might have been looking at this and other probabilistic algorithms (which should have been noted in the interview question).

Answer (score 3):

If all we can do is compare, then as pointed by a poster above, we cannot do better than O(log(N)).

But, if we know a little more about the input distribution we can do more stuff. If are told (by the interviewer :)) that the numbers are contiguous, then an O(1) solution is possible. The difference between the first element and element we are looking for will give us an exact spot we should expect to find the number.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that "If all we can do is compare, then as pointed by a poster above, we cannot do better than O(log(N))"

Answer (score 2):

Since we know the range of the numbers (M) we could perform an interpolated binary search.  Rather than bisect the search range by 1/2 bisect it by N / (HI - LO).  The result will still be O(log N) but with a lower constant.  This technique works better if we know there are no duplicates in the data, and the question seems to hint that might be the case, but it is not definitive.

See for example this blog:  [Faster than Binary Search](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2006/10/faster-than-speed-of-binary-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, As per my knowledge. In this problem you can take advantage of two hints.
1. Numbers are sorted and 2.  N & M are very large (N >> M) and M spans multiple disks

You can use a bit of randomization in this problem. Rather than using Binary search, randomly chose a point and then check if x (number to be searched) is less than or greater than current value. You can start from both ends and iteratively reduce the size of search space.  In very small iterations only you can reduce it to small domain and later you can apply binary search for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

It's a provable fact that any algorithm that does compares cannot possibly beat log(n). That means a constant time solution *cannot* compare numbers to each other. A constant time solution will involve trickery in all cases.

Given that, a constant time solution is possible with a slew of assumptions:

- The numbers are written sequentially
- You know exactly where on the number sequence starts and where exactly it ends (disk offset)
- All the disks are the same size and have the *exact* same bit capacity
- You know exactly how many bits could be written to a disk

Given those assumptions, simply multiply k times the bit size of the number. Seek to that location (O(1)) + offset and read back the correct number of bits.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about not-existence, so there is no need to search in disks.
We can check if the number X is out of  all disk's min and max range in O(1).
( number of disks are constant )

```
bool not_exists=true
for each disk_i in disks:
  not_exists &&= (X <min_element(disk_i)  || X > max_element(disk_i) )
return not_exists
```

if the result is true. then we can be sure that there is no X in disks.
otherwise X 'could be' in the disks.

Comment: that's clever!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some faster lookup times if you allow yourself the use of some meta-data.

Set up a number of indirect blocks or lists whose elements point to more indirect blocks/lists.  Repeat until you get to a desired level of direct blocks/list.  The idea is to use something similar to how some file systems access their file data (direct, indirect, doubly indirect and triply indirect blocks).  It is quite likely that for number ranges that they are requesting you will need more than triple indirection.

Each part of the number you are looking up can refer to a separate index in the indirect/direct tables.  Eventually, you will have broken the search down far enough that you can read the final section that may or may not contain the number.  Then you can search this final section with an algorithm of your choice.

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Disclaimer: I'm going to lunch in a minute and so I have not completely thought this through--it may be impractical.

Comment: This is still O(log n) - the question looks for the algorithm to beat that.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a badly phrased question.

If Bloom filters is the answer they were looking for, which is most likely, there is no need to confuse the candidate with a potential distributed/parallel algorithm element ( multiple disks ).

Assuming one disk

Bloom filters are constant time operations once the filter is built. But, to make up for false positives one will have to do binary search ( or even interpolation search like someone suggested assuming uniform distribution ) will contribute to a factor greater than constant log(n) in the binary search case.

so, it is
 O(k) + 1% * log(n) . 
O(k) constant time to check bloom filter.
then assuming 1% error rate ( false positives ) with bloom filter , that many times one will have to do binary search to make sure that it does actually exist.

I am not sure that this can be reduced to constant time with amortized analysis ( not too versed there ).

Answer (score 0):

One aspect that hasn't been mentioned yet is that the question is non-specific about what kind of computer you're using. It's trivial to do this in constant time if each hard disk just happens to be attached to its own CPU.

This seems like a cop-out, but if this question were asked by an interviewer that does distributed computing, it might be the answer they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just a humble thought.

Maybe this is more a system question than a algorithm question, let's try to think from the search engine way.

Suppose I have enough machines to have all the sorted N integers indexed, with each machine only holding fixed amount K documents representing K out of the N integers.

So in this way for any given number X, The networking time for the client query server to reach the search nodes can be treated as constant time; the time for a search node to look up a document representing number X is also constant time since the documents amount on each search node is a fixed number K.

Thus the total time is constant. However, this is more or less similar to what Enrique mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this question by  checking the size of file that holds the number and then create a number whose size is bigger than the the size of file(not talking abt int or lar

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem clearly states that you are *given* a list of size `N`, such as

```
const int N = 15;
int xs[N] = {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30};
```

You have to answer *a single query* (in less than `O(logN)`) and thus you cannot really do any preprocessing. I believe the question would have been worded differently in such case if you could go for amortized times.

`N` in practice can be really large, so even the number `N` itself may need many disks to be stored (the way I read the question : ). I think this just denotes that you cannot create a simple lookup array of size M, because `M > N`, thus no point.

So, really you cannot do better than binary search. However, as you know the max possible value of elements, which is `M` (and assuming that the data is uniformly distributed), you can guess the initial position, where to start the binary search.

This is essentially `x / M * N`, in code might be something like that:

```
double hint = static_cast<double>(x) / M; // between [0,1)
int m = static_cast<int>(hint * N); // guess the position in xs
// do binary search using m as initial "middle" point.
```

So, this guessinng, given the assumption hold, will speed up the algorithm by a nice constant. The time complexity will still be `O(lgN)`, though.