# Given a sorted list of N numbers that range over M, M>>N find or determine non-existence of a given number. Constant time if possible?

Tags: algorithm, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find existence of number in a sorted list in constant time? (Interview question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054381/find-existence-of-number-in-a-sorted-list-in-constant-time-interview-question)

First of all, I'm not sure if this is a real interview question. I found it on a website that claims that this is a Google interview question. Having said that, it seemed pretty interesting which is why I felt like putting it up here.

It's pretty much all up there. We are given a sorted list of N numbers that range over M where M>>N and N is large enough to span multiple disks.

We need to find or determine the non-existence of a given number in O(logN). This is straight forward for a smaller data set (binary search). For a data set over multiple disks, this seems much harder. It also says that there are extra points for O(1) solutions. Any ideas?

I found the question [here](http://blog.seattleinterviewcoach.com/2009/02/140-google-interview-questions.html#software_engineer).

Comment: "Multiple disks" is a red herring. The same algorithms as in memory are applicable, but slower by a rather large constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "faster than O(logN)" solution is to search each disk in parallel. Since the data is sorted, you know from looking at the 2 end points of a disk whether the number we're interested in might be on it. Then we binary search this disk for the number, giving us an O(log(N/D)) solution where D is the number of disks.

There is no constant time solution given how the question is currently phrased. I can only imagine the author left out some details in posting the question as briefly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since we know the range of the numbers (M) we could perform an interpolated binary search.  Rather than bisect the search range by 1/2 bisect it by N / (HI - LO).  The result will still be O(log N) but with a lower constant.  This technique works better if we know there are no duplicates in the data, and the question seems to hint that might be the case, but it is not definitive.

See for example this blog:  [Faster than Binary Search](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2006/10/faster-than-speed-of-binary-search.html)