# Optimality of Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, lower-bound

This may be a silly question, but does anyone know of a proof that binary search is asymptotically optimal?  That is, if we are given a sorted list of elements where the only permitted operation on those objects is a comparison, how do you prove that the search can't be done in o(lg n)?  (That's little-o of lg n, by the way.)  Note that I'm restricting this to elements where the only operation permitted operation is a comparison, since there are well-known algorithms that can beat O(lg n) on expectation if you're allowed to do more complex operations on the data (see, for example, interpolation search).

Comment: You're also assuming uniform access to all elements? Else see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_search_technique

Comment: @Bernard - nope, not a homework assignment.  I have my standards. :-)  This is just something that's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: @Paul - I'm looking for an algorithm that minimizes the number of comparisons, so the access time for each element should be irrelevant.  Also, to the best of my knowledge Fibonacci search is also O(lg n), which is asymptotically equivalent to binary search.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in your array?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but sure, let's say that duplicates are allowed.

Comment: It's enough to show that there exists an n and value (x) that requires log n. I think that's easy - just have the values 1..n and look for n-1?

Comment: Did you try searching the site? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054381/find-existence-of-number-in-a-sorted-list-in-constant-time-interview-question/3055575#3055575

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~cscskp/Algorithms/search/node11.html):

- The number of possible outcomes should be at least O(n).
- You can represent the decisions done by the algorithm by nodes of a "decision tree": if the items compare greater then it goes on way, if not it goes the other way. The nodes of the tree are the states of the algorithm and the leaves are the outcomes. So there should be at least O(n) nodes in the tree.
- Each tree on O(n) nodes has at least O(log N) levels.

Comment: That's very clever - I didn't think of representing the state of the algorithm as a tree.  This makes perfect sense; thanks so much!

Comment: @template: AFAIK optimality of heapsort/mergesort is also proven in similar way.

Comment: Could I suggest a bit more precision: Assuming all n elements are distinct, there are exactly n+1 possible outcomes (since the target value may not exist), so there are exactly n+1 *leaves* (not nodes).  A tree on n+1 *leaves* has at least log2(n+1) levels.  Maybe you're correct to say "Each tree on O(n) nodes has at least O(log n) levels" but I find it hard to reason about O() when it's on both sides of the equation like that... :)

Answer (score 1):

The logic is simple. Let's assume we have array of `n` different sorted elements.

1. There're 2 possible outcomes of 1 comparison (first element is smaller or greater). Thus, if one comparison is enough, `n <= 2`. Otherwise, if we have 3 elements (`a, b, c`) and our algorithm has 2 possible outcomes, one of 3 elements will never be selected.
2. There're 4 possible outcomes of 2 comparisons. Thus, if 2 comparisons is enough, `n <= 4`.
3. Likewise, for `k` comparisons to be enough `n` should be `n <= 2^k`.

Reverse the last inequality and you'll have logarithm: `k >= log(2, n)`.

Comment: It looks like you prove the upper bound here.

Comment: Does this change if there are duplicated elements?

Comment: Does this really work as a lower-bound proof?  You've correctly shown that you can look up an element in O(lg n) time, but have you precluded the possibility of an asymptotically faster algorithm?

Comment: @templatetypedef I've added the last step, it should be clear now.

Comment: @Paul 'Without duplicated elements' is a special case of original problem. If there's no better solution for special case, there's no better solution for the whole problem too.

Comment: Yes, I'd got there eventually too :)

Comment: @ybungalobill: Nikita proves an upper bound on the number of distinct solutions you can get with k comparisons.  His final step turns this around, giving a lower bound on the number of comparisons needed to get n distinct solutions.  (I guess this was added after your comment...)

Answer (score 1):

As Nikita described it's impossible to have something *always* better than O(log n).

Even if you allowed to do some additional operations, it's still not enough - I'm sure it's possible to prepare elements sequence where interpolation search will perform worse than binary search.

We can say interpolation search is better only because:

1. We consider average performance, not worst case.
2. Probability of each possible incoming data set is non-uniform.

So the answer is - it all depends on the additional knowledge we have about incoming data sets.

Comment: With additional knowledge there may be pretty much everything. If you sort your elements by probability, and the probability is geometric distribution, then even linear search can perform in O(1) time! Btw, it's a good idea, sometimes.